# Pivot point changes location between Edit and Object mode

Tags: animation

I am trying to animate rotating arcs in different directions, around the center of the sphere they were once part of, but the pivot point, while in the right place while in Object mode, goes to another place in Edit mode.

In the GIF below, you can see the smallest arc rotating outside of the larger one while it should stay inside, and then in Object mode both arcs rotate at the same time / in the same direction, but but this time around the correct pivot point.

I tried snapping the pivot point to the right position, but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the **Median Point** as the **[Pivot Point](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html)** to to rotate. Select **3D Cursor**:

[image: 7]

[image]

Here are some of the differences using different pivot points:

[image]